# Make all snakemake run in the temporary scratch space on SGE cluster

Tags: python, bash, snakemake

Running on a SGE cluster. I have had no issues until recently my cluster people told me that I need to start "The jobs were overloading the bossock fibres on the storage and the IO profile of the job was such that our storage had trouble
serving the requests. We will want the output files and possibly the input
files to be read and written by snakemake in scratch space, and then you
will need to copy anything you want back and delete the files in scratch."

I've been submitting snakemake with the following bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Submit to the cluster, give it a unique name
#$ -S /bin/bash

#$ -V
#$ -l h_vmem=1.9G,h_rt=20:00:00,tmem=1.9G
#$ -l tscratch=100G
#$ -pe smp 2

# join stdout and stderr output
#$ -j y
#$ -R y


if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
    RUN_NAME=$1
else
    RUN_NAME=$""
fi

#setup scratch space
scratch=/scratch0/annbrown/$JOB_ID



#FOLDER=submissions/$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
FOLDER=${scratch}submissions/$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")
mkdir -p $FOLDER
# make /a symlink of my snakemake pipeline in the scratch space
ln -s /home/annbrown/pipelines/rna_seq_snakemake $FOLDER

cd $FOLDER/rna_seq_snakemake


cp config/config.yaml $FOLDER/$RUN_NAMEconfig.yaml


snakemake -s rna_seq.snakefile \
--jobscript cluster_qsub.sh \
--cluster-config config/cluster.yaml \
--cluster-sync "qsub -R y -l h_vmem={cluster.h_vmem},h_rt={cluster.h_rt} -pe {cluster.pe} -o $FOLDER" \
-j 25 \
--nolock \
--rerun-incomplete \
--latency-wait 100

#copy work out of scratch -you may need to change the destination

cp -r $FOLDER ~/annbrown

#delete scratch once you have finished (very important)
rm -rf $scratch
```

But whenever snakemake starts going it's still writing it's subnmission temporary files to the wrong spot

```
/SAN/vyplab/alb_projects/pipelines/rna_seq_snakemake/.snakemake/tmp.gkxzqok7/snakejob.run_star_pe.139.sh
#$ -S /bin/bash

#$ -cwd
#$ -V
#$ -l h_vmem=4G,h_rt=6:00:00,tmem=4G


# join stdout and stderr output
#$ -j y
#$ -sync y
#$ -R y




cd /SAN/vyplab/alb_projects/pipelines/rna_seq_snakemake && \
/share/apps/python-3.7.2-shared/bin/python3.7 \
-m snakemake /SAN/vyplab/alb_projects/data/muscle/analysis/STAR_aligned/12_9_5_18.Aligned.out.bam --snakefile /SAN/vyplab/alb_projects/pipelines/rna_seq_snakemake/rna_seq.snakefile \
--force -j --keep-target-files --keep-remote \
--wait-for-files /SAN/vyplab/alb_projects/pipelines/rna_seq_snakemake/.snakemake/tmp.gkxzqok7 /SAN/vyplab/vyplab_reference_genomes/STAR/human/GRCh38/star_indices_overhang150/SA /SAN/vyplab/alb_projects/data/muscle/analysis/merged_fastqs/12_9_5_18_1.merged.fastq.gz /SAN/vyplab/alb_projects/data/muscle/analysis/merged_fastqs/12_9_5_18_2.merged.fastq.gz --latency-wait 100 \
 --attempt 1 --force-use-threads \
--wrapper-prefix https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake-wrappers/raw/ \
   --allowed-rules run_star_pe --nocolor --notemp --no-hooks --nolock \
--mode 2
```

Has anyone gotten snakemake to run in temporary scratch spaces? I'm not really sure if I'm meant to be using the shadow directive or what to be honest.

Comment: Can you show us one of the rules in the Snakefile? Probably the input of these functions are relative to where the Snakefile is located. Simplest solution would be to just copy the whole pipeline into your scratch space and run from there.